# Multimodule project with multi-database connection

Tags: spring-boot

[image]

I created a multi-module project, the modules are:

- Domain
- Web
- Core-Service
- Other-Service

The Core-Service is connected to a POSGRESQL DB and the OTHER-SERVICE is connected to an oracle DB.

The main application or starting point is the web module. The Domain module contains the model/entity that is also connected to the posgresql db. The web module is just a controller that will redirect the request on their certain services.

How can I configure this multi-module project such that when I run the main application, the CORE-SERVICE and OTHER-SERVICE will automatically connect to their respective Database. I am just getting error on the JPA connection. I think I am missing something. Thanks in advance